# How do bottleneck architectures work in neural networks?

Tags: residuals, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

We define a bottleneck architecture as the type found in the [ResNet](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf) paper where [two 3x3 conv layers] are replaced by [one 1x1 conv, one 3x3 conv, and another 1x1 conv layer]. [image]

I understand that the 1x1 conv layers are used as a form of dimension reduction (and restoration), which is explained in [another post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194142/what-does-1x1-convolution-mean-in-a-neural-network.).  However, I am unclear about why this structure as effective as the original layout.

Some good explanations might include: What [stride length](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/3ywi6x/deep_residual_learning_the_bottleneck/) is used and at what layers?  What are example input and output dimensions of each module?  How are the 56x56 feature maps represented in the diagram above?  Do the 64-d refer to the number of filters, why does this differ from the 256-d filters?  How many weights or FLOPs are used at each layer?

Any discussion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think it may help with generalization and prevention of over fitting. But that is just a vague recollection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The bottleneck architecture is used in very deep networks due to computational considerations.

To answer your questions:

1. 56x56 feature maps are not represented in the above image. This block is taken from a ResNet with input size 224x224. 56x56 is the downsampled version of the input at some intermediate layer.
2. 64-d refers to the number of feature maps(filters). The bottleneck architecture has 256-d, simply because it is meant for much deeper network, which possibly take higher resolution image as input and hence require more feature maps.
3. Refer [this figure](http://ethereon.github.io/netscope/#/gist/db945b393d40bfa26006) for parameters of each bottleneck layer in ResNet 50.

Comment: For future readers, I should mention that I think the 1x1 convs have stride=1 and pad=0, to preserve (WxH) of 56x56.  Similarly, the 3x3 convs have stride=1 and pad=1 to preserve size as well.

Comment: Still I dont understand. It seems both of them have the similar amount of parameters, in that case I still dont understand the purpose of bootleneck layer.

Comment: I really think that the 2nd point in *Newstein*'s answer is misleading. The `64-d` or `256-d` should refer to the *number of channels* of the *input feature map* — not the number of input feature maps. Consider the "bottleneck" block (the right of the figure) in the OP's question as an example: - `256-d` means that we have a single input feature map with dimension `n x n x 256`. The `1x1, 64` in the figure means ` 64` *filters*, each is `1x1` and has `256` channels (`1x1x256`). - So here we can see that the convolution of a single filter (`1x1x256`) with an input feature map (`n x n x 256`) gi

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand, illustration on the right shows that input to this block already has 256 features. So we are deep into some ResNet architecture and already created 256 features (we lost some w x h due to conv 3x3 before but gained features instead).

Still, calculating 256 channels (features) can take too much time, and authors proposed using 1x1 conv layer with stride 1 and padding 0 that keeps image's w x h as it was but in the meantime reduces depth, number of output channels to 64.

Thus, but using this bottleneck, at first layer you are shoving w x h x 256 element into conv 1x1 layer that will pass through just w x h x 64

Answer (score 1):

I just want to answer your questions:

**What stride length is used and at what layers?**
Stride is not relevant in this discussion/figure. The "layers" are represented as rectangles and are 2d convolutional layers.

**How are the 56x56 feature maps represented in the diagram above?**
Feature maps are the result of a conv. layer. So they should be positioned right after the rectangles (which are the convolutional layers). The dimension of the feature maps are not provided in the figure but can be calculated.

**Do the 64-d refer to the number of filters, why does this differ from the 256-d filters?**
Yes, they indicate the number of filters/kernels used in this layer. A lower number means that fewer filters are used which means that the network has less capacity to represent/store information. By this mechanism, a bottleneck is obtained and it is assumed that the network learns to focus on the most relevant things and remove noise.